# Logging Exceptions - How to make best use of them

Tags: java, testing, logging, exception

I came across something which is new to me today...`Logging Exceptions`. I saw many people do it, but I don't understand why they do it and how they make best use of them.

```
catch (Throwable ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenericDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new DBException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
```

say this above code snippet is for logging exceptions of database update method `update ()`.

When the `Logger.getLogger(GenericDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);` executes, what is really happening. Can something be accessed from a file as a result of this? if so how an where?

Can developers use logging when doing component testing? or unit testing?

Comment: It's just like any other logging - the exception stack trace gets written to the log file.

Comment: how do you access that file? is it a history of log...perhaps from ages ago?

Answer (score 4):

The `Logger` framework can be configured to write to a file, to send an email, to post to a support group, or to call the President.  This way, the developer can leave it to the operational staff how best to alert when errors of this kind happen.

Other than that, the stack traces are used in the normal way for debugging during any kind of testing or production issue resolution.

Comment: I like 'call the President', +1